# Toshiba "eco mode" equivalent

Tags: power-management, cpu-load, temperature

I have a Toshiba Satellite R830 dual-boot Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 7.

On Windows, when I turn "eco mode" on, the fan is much more silent and temperatures are considerably lower. On Ubuntu, eco mode does not work.

Is there an alternative way to "throttle" the processor or limit power consumption with the final aim being to keep temperatures low and maybe extend battery life?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Cpu frequency control' provides what you want, so you should install indicator-cpufreq package.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:artfwo/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

And Launch "Startup Applications"

[image: Startup Applications]

Then click "Add" to add a new startup application. In command area type `indicator-cpufreq` , in name area type whatever you want.

[image: add new startup applications]
Logout and then login or restart your computer.
Also, you can launch this indicator in terminal with the same command.

Now, you can choose cpu freq for power save.
[image: indicator cpu frequency]

Original Resource: http://handytutorial.com/cpu-frequency-scaling-indicator-on-ubuntu-12-04-12-10/

Comment: I installed this and it works. However with Ubuntu 12.10 there's no need to add a ppa and it was automatically added to startup items.

Comment: Yes, I have realized that when i was installing but i don't need to change my answer, because some readers may have another versions of ubuntu or other distributions whose official repositories can't contain this package.